# How do I translate "А попросту говоря, эта твоя бравура меня ..."?

Tags: перевод

Hello I would like to know what is the meaning of the following phrase:

А попросту говоря, эта твоя бравура меня заебала

Both Google and Yandex give meaningless translations in regards to the second part of the phrase, and looking for it with Google images does not help much

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! I've edited the caption of your question because it contains an expletive. Question titles can be seen on the cross-site sidebar, so expletives are not welcome in the titles. Cheers!

Comment: I don't think it's off-topic, it's a question about Russian expressions, not about English language. It won't fit English.SE.

Comment: @Quassnoi: The help section clearly states that questions from Russian to other languages are on-topic. Why is this one closed? http://russian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: first question I ask here so I hope I didn't break any rule, I do not understand why I should put such a question in the English language SE - care to explain so I don't repeat the mistake?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: I don't know, it wasn't me who closed it. You might want to address shabunc who did it or alternatively cast enough reopen votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

бравура/бравада is a French borrowing, means showing off or bragging.

Translation:

> Simply put, I'm freaking sick of your bragging.

Comment: To even better reflect the meaning, I'd say "fucking tired" or "fucking sick".

Comment: @AleksG "freaking" means exactly that.

Comment: Not quite. It's similar, but there are differences in meaning as well as censoring opportunities.

Comment: "bragging" is about what is said but "бравура" in this case is more about  a clearly inappropriate overconfident cocky *behavior*, not just words. Also, "freaking sick" is too weak; you may expect the situation to escalate if you hear the phrase and  you don't assume a humbler demeanor immediately.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian well, "bragging" was the closest one I could think of.

Answer (score 2):

The word "бравура" seems not to be used nowadays except in the expression "бравурная музыка" (bravura music). Otherwise people use the word "бравада" (bravado). Both words (French or Italian origin) also present in English (bravado, bravura) and are quite understandable due to the word "brave". It's not clear from the context either that's about some kind of bragging or (bravura) music. The last word is obscene. It means "pisses me off" though a bit ruder.

So, the approximate translation is "To say it simple, those your bravura pisses me off".

Comment: a bit ruder? :(  a barefaced insult, in conjaction with *эта твоя ...*

Comment: В России коммуникации между людьми (чаще между мужчинами), слово "заебала, заебал, заебало" часто используются. Например, если один друг часто жалуется на что-то (на жену, на начальника, на тёщу), другой friend может сказать :. «Ты трахаться (заебал) меня с нытьем" Это не будет вопиющим оскорблением.

Comment: @МатвейДёмин: you might mean *"затрахал своим нытьем"*  instead of *"трахаться"* The phrase is meant to express emotion (in a vulgar manner); it is also an insult -- it implies that the person is a whiner.